Extending of Sobolev function in the domain with non-smooth boundaries
I have a function $u(x, t) \in W^{2, 1}_q$ (2 spatial, 1 time Sobolev derivatives in $L_q$ space) with $q>3$ defined in a parabolic cilynder $x \in (-1, 1)$, $t > 0$. Note that Sobolev embedding theorem gives $u \in C^0$, $u_x \in C^0$.
Inside the cylinder I have a domain with not smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. I know that $u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ and $u_x|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$. Does the function $v(x, t) = u(x, t)I_{\Omega}$ ($v(x, t) = u(x, t)$ for $(x, t) \in \Omega$ and 0 otherwise) is $W^{2, 1}_q$
I tried to intergate product on test function by parts, but encountered difficulties due to nonsmoothness of $\partial \Omega$.
Does someone knows the answer or can give a reference to book/review for trace operators in nonsmooth domains?
